# How can I obtain the approximate geographic location of a web user?

Tags: geolocation

It would be of significant benefit to my business if we could display information corresponding to a user's location when they reach our website's home page. I understand that trying to obtain geolocation from only an IP address is not an exact science, but we're willing to take what we can get.

What techniques are there available for determining approximate locations of a web user?

Comment: where do you want to gather this data? from the client upon interaction with your site , e.g. form submission or login, or on the server triggered by an arbitry even?

Comment: @Sky Sanders: This information needs to be available on the home page, without previously knowing the user or asking them to specify their location (where possible).

Comment: 'on' the home page. does that mean the server needs to know to serve the geocentric content or that there is going to be some map or geocentric client side javascript consuming the information.

Comment: @Sky Sanders: The server will need to know in order to serve region-specific content. Having this information delivered via an AJAX call is completely acceptable, so client-side and server-side technologies are both acceptable answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

your best bet is to use the google apis. You can have the IP set in a form field that is submitted. Or you could use a [.net api](http://www.codeproject.com/info/search.aspx?artkw=google+maps+api)

[google.loader.ClientLocation to get a person's lat/long using their IP address](http://snipplr.com/view/7985/googleloaderclientlocation-to-get-a-persons-latlong-using-their-ip-address/)

---

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi?key=ABQIAAAALDWeTDQHOJCbCf0JnUqL8BT2yXp_ZAY8_ufC3CFXhHIE1NvwkxQA7AE8xB9MyWgHECPY2qimOp7BUQ"></script>
    <script src="scripts/clientLocation.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function $g(id) {
            return document.getElementById(id);
        }

        function displayLocation(latitudeEl, longitudeEl, cityEl, regionEl, countryEl, country_codeEl) {
            var cloc = new ClientLocation.Location(google.loader.ClientLocation);
            if (latitudeEl) latitudeEl.innerHTML = cloc.latitude;
            if (longitudeEl) longitudeEl.innerHTML = cloc.longitude;
            if (cityEl) cityEl.innerHTML = cloc.address.city;
            if (regionEl) regionEl.innerHTML = cloc.address.region;
            if (country) country.innerHTML = cloc.address.country;
            if (country_codeEl) country_codeEl.innerHTML = cloc.address.country_code;
        }

        function init() {
            displayLocation($g("latitude"), $g("longitude"), $g("city"), $g("region"), $g("country"), $g("country_code"));
        }
    </script>

</head>
<body onload="init()">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        latitude : <span id="latitude"></span>
        <br />
        longitude : <span id="longitude"></span>
        <br />
        city : <span id="city"></span>
        <br />
        region : <span id="region"></span>
        <br />
        country : <span id="country"></span>
        <br />
        country_code : <span id="country_code"></span>
        <br />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

---

```
// <copyright file="clientLocation.js" company="Sky Sanders">
// This source is placed in the Public Domain.
// http://skysanders.net/subtext
// Attribution is appreciated.
// </copyright>


/*
object literal format for google.loader.clientlocation  
{
"latitude": 33.324,
"longitude": -111.867,
"address": {
"city": "Chandler",
"region": "AZ",
"country": "USA",
"country_code": "US"
}
}
*/

var ClientLocation = {};

ClientLocation.Address = function() {
    /// <field name="city" type="String" />
    /// <field name="region" type="String" />
    /// <field name="country" type="String" />
    /// <field name="country_code" type="String" />
    /// <returns type="ClientLocation.Address"/>
    if (arguments.length > 0) {
        this.city = arguments[0].city;
        this.region = arguments[0].region;
        this.country = arguments[0].country;
        this.country_code = arguments[0].country_code;
        return;
    }
    else {
        this.city = "";
        this.region = "";
        this.country = "";
        this.country_code = "";
    }

}
ClientLocation.Location = function() {
    /// <field name="latitude" type="Number" />
    /// <field name="longitude" type="Number" />
    /// <field name="address" type="ClientLocation.Address" />
    if (arguments.length > 0) {

        this.latitude = arguments[0].latitude;
        this.longitude = arguments[0].longitude;
        this.address = arguments[0].address;

    }
    else {
        this.latitude = 0;
        this.longitude = 0;
        this.address = undefined;
    }

}
```

Comment: Looks appropriate to my needs. I shall have a delve.

Answer (score 2):

You can't tell for sure and it can be inaccurate but services do exist to map IP addresses to their geographical location.

I just Binged for it and I got: http://www.ip2location.com/

They tend to need subscriptions to their service, though

Answer (score 1):

The best option is to licence the data from someone like [MaxMind](http://www.maxmind.com/app/ip-location) - they use a lot of different methods, some of them pretty clever, to find out the location associated with an IP address and in my experience their data is pretty easy to integrate with as well.